# Implement Python Flash Controller Methods Generated from OpenAPI Generator

Tags: python, flask, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/python-flask) to generate a Python Flask web app from an OpenAPI specification.  A generated controller method looks like this:

```
def doStuff(body):  # noqa: E501
    return 'do some magic!'
```

What is the best practice for filling in the implementation of these generated controller classes?  Do I copy what was generated and then modify that?  I can't modify in the generated directory obviously because the generator will regenerate and overwrite my changes.

What happens if I add an endpoint in the OpenAPI spec that causes an additional method to be generated?  Do I have to manually copy this new method into my implementation code?

Comment: Have you found your answer ? I have the same issue.

Comment: I haven't found a great way to do it yet.  What I ended up doing is copying the generated file to a different directory, and implementing the method there.  Because I'm packaging this app up in a Docker image, I use my Dockerfile to place the impl class in the correct place in the structure, overwriting the generated class.  I'm not thrilled with this solution though, because it doesn't address how to enforce that new generated methods are implemented.